# Nginx as reverse proxy for GitLab with SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, https, gitlab

I have GitLab's nginx setup to listen at 127.0.0.1:8088 . Then I have a system nginx (installed via apt-get on Ubuntu) setup as reverse proxy with HTTPS:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server                    localhost:8088 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     gitlab.myhost.com;
    return          301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# let gitlab deal with the redirection
server {
    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 gitlab.myhost.com;

    ssl_certificate             /srv/www/gitlab.myhost.com.unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /srv/www/gitlab.myhost.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

        proxy_pass              http://gitlab;
    }
}
```

This worked okay, and basically all requests are forwarded to HTTPS. However, because GitLab still thinks it's running in HTTP, a few graphics resources on the page, and Gravatar are using HTTP scheme. How do I solve this problem?

Of course I understand that I can configure `gitlab.rb` to use an HTTPS URL. However when this is done, GitLab will start asking for certificates to setup its own nginx. I really only need its own nginx to run in HTTP, at local loopback.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a old question but,

nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
set external_url="https://whatever"
```

then find right way down in the nginx area.

```
inside the nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = { directive add
"X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
```

this will assume your SSL is built on a proxy further out. And url rewrite all http to https

Answer (score 1):

Better to follow the instructions at [Configure a reverse proxy or load balancer SSL termination](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/index.html#configure-a-reverse-proxy-or-load-balancer-ssl-termination) which are (in summmary, with additions from personal experience):

Edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
external_url "https://gitlab.myhost.com"
nginx['listen_port'] = 8088
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

Then issue a

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```